# Infinite pop up error while using phonegap 1.3.0 with HTML5 and jquery to create android application?

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

I've been developing android application using `html5`, `jquery` and `phonegap` default provided by `Dreamweaver` `cs5.5`. It all works fine. But when I tried to use the latest version of phonegap 1.3.0., there are some prompt poping. The first one is ' gap : ["Network Status", "getConnectionInfo","Network Status0",true] '. And after this one, other appears ("usePolling gap_callbackServer:", "getPort ..." , "getToken"). Finally, there is one that doesn't
disappear : "gap_poll". (refer to http://osdir.com/ml/phonegap/2011-09/msg01372.html). I tried including phonegap.jar. But the problem is still the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to error in upgrading phonegap. You need to upgrade whole phonegap plugin. Please follow the following link to upgrade phonegap in dreamweaver..

[Phonegap in Dreamweaver CS5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643581/phonegap-in-dreamweaver-cs5-5)

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem is brief But in my phonegap application, I use the network connectivity methods to check for the network i.e type  etc.  Your description of the problem means that some functions are being called without your knowledge. I would suggest you use something like Safari developer tool to trace your jscript logic to the point where this methods are being called then take further action

Comment: I simply compiled the example downloaded from http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou. and i got the above problem. Does the phonegap 1.3.0 really works with HTML5 and jquery to generate android apps? Because I've developed android apps using the phonegap provided by Dreamweaver CS5.5 but I'm not able by phonegap 1.3.0.

Comment: I havent used Phonegap with Dreamweaver but given the role of Phonegap in the software stack, it shouldnt care what HTML version you are employing.What matters is the version of browser the device will have since support for HTML 5 is dependent on the browser AND Phonegap apps are Browser apps.