# Phonegap in Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova, dreamweaver

What is the version of `Phonegap` used by `Dreamweaver CS5.5`? I've tried to replace the default `phonegap.js` file with the latest version which gave error. Is it good idea to replace the existing `phonegap.js` file with latest version?

Comment: you would have to update the phonegap plugin too. u cant just update the js file.

Comment: so can you please me how to update phonegap plugin?

Comment: http://idoitonamac.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-upgrade-phonegap-in-adobe.html

Comment: I think this upgrade only works on Mac. I'm using windows platform for android app development. Even though I tried to upgrade in windows I got error. I couldn't even compile the application. What might be the solution?

Comment: for android u just need to replace the phonegap.js and phonegap.jar..
replace both with the new ones, add the new one to the dependency and it should work fine...

Comment: I've followed your steps. The application is compiled. But while running both in simulator as well as in device, it generates the following error : 
"The application {application_name} has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.". My main issue is to control back button no matter which of phonegap is used. Is there any solution? What is version of phonegap used in Dreamweaver CS5.5?
 Thanx ghostCoder

Comment: see the logs in logcat. you can find the reason why its crashing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Upgrading the phonegap of adobe dreamweaver cs5.5

1. Download latest phonegap version.
2. Extract the downloaded zip file
3. Open the “Android” folder in the extracted zip.
4. Remove version from the filenames:  Rename phonegap.1.3.0.jar to phonegap.jar and phonegap.1.3.0.js to phonegap.js
5. Copy and overwrite phonegap.js to C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp\assets\www
6. Copy and overwrite phonegap.jar to C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp\libs
7. Copy the folder “xml”, with the plugins.xml file in it, to C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\NativeAppFramework\DWPhoneGap\android\PhoneGapApp\res
8. In your existing mobile phonegap application, replace the old phonegap.js with the new one. And also delete previously builds binary folders like (“com.yourcompany.application_Android”)

http://www.eracer.de/dreamweaver-5-5-update-to-latest-phonegap-version-android/