# Dreamweaver CS 5.5 Android Error - package com.phonegap does not exist

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver CS 5.5 to convert my HTML code to an Android APK.  It worked in the past, but suddenly, even for new sites that I create, I get this popup message:

> The build of "yourapp" failed to complete successfully.  Please
>   consult the build log at
>   C:\Users\MyUserFolder\Desktop\com.company.yourapp_Android\buildlog.log
>   for additional details.

The `buildlog.log` file shows that I run into six compilation errors having to do with missing packages and symbols:

```
DefaultActivity.java:6: package com.phonegap does not exist.
    import com.phonegap.*;
    ^

DefaultActivity.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol: class DroidGap
    public class DefaultActivity extends DroidGap
                                         ^
...
cannot find symbol --> variable super (3 times)
...
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
```

I still have my Android SDK Path pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` in the `Configure Application Framework`.  I checked the SDK folder and underlying files in that location.  It appears to still exist and be intact.

I checked my Adobe > Dreamweaver folders and saw that the `phonegap.jar` was still there. I even followed the directions from another post on how to update Dreamweaver with the latest phonegap, but I still get the error. (This was the post on how to update: [Phonegap in Dreamweaver CS5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643581/phonegap-in-dreamweaver-cs5-5?rq=1) )

It's been about a month or more since I last tried it and was successful, so any number of updates to my work machine for any of the related software or operating system could have broken it.  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I figured it out!  The jar file structure is now different...depending on the version of phonegap included in the libs dir.  Examine that jar file carefully (in an archive app such as winzip or extract it or view in a Java IDE).  Modify code accordingly.  Done.

Comment: Great that you solved the issue and thanks for writing an answer! Feel free to accept your own answer so it is easy to tell this issue was resolved